# occasional use of your opposable thumbs

Tags: meaning-in-context

What do you interpret the meaning of the expression "occasional use of your opposable thumbs" in the following context:

> All pets really need is your care and the occasional use of your
> opposable thumbs. In return, you get love and companionship and the
> kind of unwavering appreciation that even the most devoted offspring
> can’t consistently provide. ([vogue](https://www.vogue.com/article/pet-moms-unshakeable-interspecies-bond?fbclid=IwAR07q1_-Neb9oBsk5NfD95aJFChTXS7C6Y97aZl3XyNhy50_7gKBJR59kWU))

Answer (score 2):

I take it to mean your doing those things that require being able to grab things, from direct care like brushing to indirect like opening a can or working a doorknob.

Comment: Attention, please:
In return, you get love and companionship and the kind of unwavering appreciation that even the most devoted offspring can’t consistently provide.